# Trouble with output in PHP with JSON object (possibly array?)

Tags: php, json

I'm having troubles getting a JSON object (possibly an array?) to output using PHP. My question is: How do I get only a displayName from the following (shortened) JSON object using PHP?

```
{"Response":
  {"results":
    [{"user":
      {"membershipId":"6343960","displayName":"J Raider"},"hasPendingApplication":false},
     {"user":
      {"membershipId":"4479502","displayName":"T Ellis"},"hasPendingApplication":false}]
  }
}
```

What I've tried so far:

```
var_dump($json); 
echo $json; 
echo $json->Response->results->user->displayName;
echo $json->Response->results[0]->user->displayName; 
echo $json->Response->results[0]->user[0]->displayName; 
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json)
```

My results have either been "null" "NULL" or simply no output.
I am pulling from the Bungie API using the following code:

```
<?php 
    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Group/1179713/Members/?lc=en&fmt=true&currentPage=1&platformType=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));

$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); // edited to correct curl_init to  curl_exec

var_dump($json);

?>
```

I am aiming to do this as a web service using PHP. The Bungie API documentation says a JavaScript GET request will not work, so I'd like to stick with PHP for the request and the output.

To clarify my question: how do I use PHP to output the displayName from this JSON object?

Thanks in advance for your help and please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($json, true))`

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($json, true)) returns "NULL" :(

Comment: wheres your `curl_exec`?

Comment: @Kisaragi great attention to detail! I had curl_init instead of curl_exec (D'oh!). This also had me looking at other details to verify everything else and I found the culprit to be the URL. It's supposed to start with "https://WWW.bungie....." I was missing the 3 w's. When I checked my URL with the Simple REST Client Chrome extension it was silently fixing my URL. Thank you for helping me find this error with your question about about the curl_exec. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure this is failing because you arent executing your curl post:

`$json = json_decode(curl_init($ch));`

should be

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: great attention to detail! I had curl_init instead of curl_exec (D'oh!). This also had me looking at other details to verify everything else and I found the culprit to be the URL. It's supposed to start with "https://WWW.bungie....." I was missing the 3 w's. When I checked my URL with the Simple REST Client Chrome extension it was silently fixing my URL. Thank you for helping me find this error with your question about about the curl_exec. :)

Answer (score 0):

just use the `json_decode()` function then iterate through the array in results like so

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);//this will give anarray from your json 
$obj = $decoded->Response->results;
foreach ($obj as $ar) {
  $displayName = $ar->user->displayName;
  echo $displayName . "<br>";
}
```

**let me know if you need more help**

Comment: Your code looks like it should work but it doesn't produce an output in my situation.

Comment: Are you sure that $json is not empty, try print it with print_r

Comment: Using print_r($jason) produces no output, however, I hit the same URL with the same header through the Chrome extension "Simple REST Client" and can verify there is supposed to be a JSON object that gets returned. I used the same cURL GET request method at a different endpoint on the API and received a JSON object that I could print using print_r. The difference in the other JSON object was that there were no [ ] brackets. From what I can tell, I'm using the right URL and the right request method, but something is wrong when I try to output.

Comment: Could you repost the second json?